# Change Groupwise 7 User Password from NetWare Server Console

Tags: novell

I have a Groupwise 7 server in place that we use for testing purposes.  The previous administrator didn't bother to make a note of any of the account passwords on the machine.  I have access to the Server Console...but I can't login via ConsoleOne or anything like that.  Is there a command line utility that I can run from the Server Console to reset a Groupwise user password?  I just need to have one account up and running for testing.  If there's a CLI utility I can use to be able to create a new account, that would work just as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...I'm kinda stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late with my answer.  You can user GWcheck to reset a users password.